# Tensorflow Operation Documentation

Tags: c++, tensorflow, protocol-buffers

In the Tensorflow [source](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/ops/array_ops.cc#L2519), I see,

```
REGISTER_OP("BroadcastGradientArgs")
    .Input("s0: T")
    .Input("s1: T")
    .Output("r0: T")
    .Output("r1: T")
    .Attr("T: {int32, int64} = DT_INT32")
    .SetShapeFn([](InferenceContext* c) {
      ... uninteresting details ...
    })
    .Doc(R"doc(                                                                                                              
Return the reduction indices for computing gradients of s0 op s1 with broadcast.                                             

This is typically used by gradient computations for a broadcasting operation.                                                
)doc");
```

In Python, I can do the following,

```
>>> from tensorflow.python.ops import gen_array_ops
>>> gen_array_ops._InitOpDefLibrary()._ops['BroadcastGradientArgs'].op_def
name: "BroadcastGradientArgs"
input_arg {
  name: "s0"
  type_attr: "T"
}
... more stuff ...
attr {
  name: "T"
  type: "type"
  ... uninteresting details ...
}
```

Note that I am getting in Python the Protobuf definition (I removed some for brevity) of the TF operation. I want to get the documentation section of the definition that I see in the C++ code. How do I get it?

Comment: That information (.Doc) exist in the TF source code BUT it's not been exported through the python wrappers and hence not available in Python. Look [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/a3e636c0f561e2ac6d9f8a0044fbe09acb003803/tensorflow/python/framework/python_op_gen.cc), this is where `op_def` that you use in your python gets generated. Some code needs to be implemented here so you can reach to those documentation in python.

Comment: Thanks. It appears that https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/a3e636c0f561e2ac6d9f8a0044fbe09acb003803/tensorflow/core/framework/op_def_util.cc#L684 is where the descriptions are removed from the OpDef. Is this true? If I delete the line https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/a3e636c0f561e2ac6d9f8a0044fbe09acb003803/tensorflow/python/framework/python_op_gen.cc#L708 will the OpDef's documentation still exist in the Protobuf?

Comment: Un-commenting that line leads to a series of problems with protobuf. Perhaps there is a better way. https://github.com/google/protobuf/issues/2798

Comment: I don't think the fix is that easy..

Comment: @arash It wasn't easy at all. See my answer. I hope you Google guys do something with those issues! Very painful

Comment: That sounds about right: patching TF and proto... I am not with google guys :-)

Comment: Oh. I assumed. You seemed to know a lot about TF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was painful. You need to patch TF and Protobuf

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/8207
https://github.com/google/protobuf/issues/2798

And then you need to additionally comment out the line,
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/a3e636c0f561e2ac6d9f8a0044fbe09acb003803/tensorflow/python/framework/python_op_gen.cc#L708

Rebuilding and running gave,

```
bazel build --config=opt //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package && \
bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/build_pip_package /tmp/tensorflow_pkg && \
sudo pip install --upgrade /tmp/tensorflow_pkg/tensorflow-1.0.0*.whl
```

And executing my test,

```
$ python -c "from tensorflow.python.ops import gen_array_ops; print gen_array_ops._InitOpDefLibrary()._ops['BroadcastGradientArgs'].op_def"
name: "BroadcastGradientArgs"
input_arg {
  name: "s0"
  type_attr: "T"
}
input_arg {
  name: "s1"
  type_attr: "T"
}
output_arg {
  name: "r0"
  type_attr: "T"
}
output_arg {
  name: "r1"
  type_attr: "T"
}
attr {
  name: "T"
  type: "type"
  default_value {
    type: DT_INT32
  }
  allowed_values {
    list {
      type: DT_INT32
      type: DT_INT64
    }
  }
}
summary: "Return the reduction indices for computing gradients of s0 op s1 with broadcast."
description: "This is typically used by gradient computations for a broadcasting operation."
```

That took way too much Regex ...